# Prevent duplicate claims added via AddClaimAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, claims-based-identity

We're using ASP.NET Identity in an MVC 5 app. We have a page that allows users and their claims to be added by admin. However, using the following lines, I can keep adding a user with the same role claim, thus creating duplicate items (the `AspNetUserClaims` table has an "autonumber" column for the primary key so we can keep adding the same role to the same user):

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
await userManager.AddClaimAsync("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SomeRole"));
```

Note that I'm adding a claim for an arbitrary user, not the logged on user. If it were the logged on user, I could simply call `User.IsInRole("SomeRole")`. And the `xxxx` is the user's GUID.

In this scenario, I'm thinking of using the following DB call to check before adding a role:

```
public static async Task<bool> UserHasClaim(string userId, 
    string claimType, string claimValue)
{
    using (var db = new MyEntities())
    {
        return await db.AspNetUserClaims
            .AnyAsync(x => x.UserId == userId && x.ClaimType == 
                  claimType && x.ClaimValue == claimValue);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I know that the `ClaimsPrincipal` contains a method `.HasClaim(...)` but I can't figure out how to create a `ClaimsPrincipal` from that user and then run the method. Thanks.

Comment: Creating a db query **every time** you add a claim sounds like an overkill. Why don't you read data from the db once, in advance, group/select distinct and then issue claims from an in memory collection?

Comment: Thought about that too, @WiktorZychla. But wanted some built-in mechanism from the Identity Framework to do it, if possible